# Nath Sampraday related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can we ask [Nath Sampraday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nath) related questions on Hinduism Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Yes, the Nath Sampradaya is on-topic here.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It's an answer so please post that as an answer so that OP can accept.

Comment: @TriyiguNarayanMani Thank you sir for asking whether that topic is valid to be discussed on our site or not. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Keshav commented above

> Yes, the Nath Sampradaya is on-topic here

And I agree with it.